# In Excel VBA, how to convert SUM function to its explicit form?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The excel cell has a formula of form `=SUM(I1:I5)`. How can we convert it into its explicit form:

```
=I1+I2+I3+I4+I5
```

Comment: There is no built in way to do this. Did you want to manipulate strings yourself to accomplish this?

Comment: To do this *the right way*, you would need to be able to parse the Excel formula syntax; then you have code that understands how `I1:I5` stands for a `Range` of 5 individual cells. Anything else is a hack (that might work!). That said it begs the question... *why*?

Comment: Is it worth asking why you'd want to?  I'm under the impression that `=SUM(I1:I5)` is much faster - _Evaluate Formula_ resolves the formula in one step, while the other way takes nine steps.  Not sure if that's a good way of seeing if a formula is faster....

Comment: Also, `=SUM(I1:I5)` and `=I1+I2+I3+I4+I5` are **not** the same thing.

Comment: G**damn it @Rory.... I need to know now.  Why not?  I thought what goes on behind the scenes is different, but the result is the same.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Enter `'1`, `2` and `TRUE` into three cells and compare the results of SUM and +. Then change one of the cells to `hello` and see what happens. :)

Comment: @Rory ah yeah, forgot about sum ignoring text.  Never considered the TRUE/FALSE bit of that though.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon To answer your why, the expanded formula will be saved in csv that, in turn, will be read by another app that has nothing to do with excel functions. Tnx

Comment: @JohnSnow it seems you need to work on the other app to be able to handle expressions and functions instead of reverse engineering excel functions. Or forget about expressions and just use the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a post on Code Golf. Here's my version of a function that can do this.

```vb
Function ExplicitSum(ByVal expression As String) As String
    Dim strStart As Long, strEnd As Long
    strStart = InStr(1, UCase(expression), "SUM(") + 4
    If strStart = 0 Then
        'SUM not found
        ExplicitSum = expression
        Exit Function
    End If
    strEnd = InStr(strStart + 1, expression, ")")
    If strEnd = 0 Then
        'closing bracket not found
        ExplicitSum = expression
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim LeftText As String, RightText As String, AddressText As String
    LeftText = Replace(Left(expression, strStart - 1), "sum(", "(", Compare:=vbTextCompare)
    AddressText = Mid(expression, strStart, strEnd - strStart)
    RightText = Right(expression, Len(expression) - strEnd + 1)
    
    If InStr(1, UCase(RightText), "SUM(") <> 0 Then
        'Recursion will handle multiple sums in the same formula
        RightText = ExplicitSum(RightText)
    End If

    Dim SumRange As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set SumRange = Range(AddressText)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If SumRange Is Nothing Then
        'Invalid AddressText - Named Ranges or Indirect reference
        ExplicitSum =  LeftText & AddressText & RightText
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim Addresses() As String
    ReDim Addresses(1 To SumRange.Cells.Count)
    
    Dim cell As Range, i As Long: i = 1
    For Each cell In SumRange
        Addresses(i) = cell.Address(False, False)
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
    
    ExplicitSum = LeftText & Join(Addresses, "+") & RightText
End Function
```

Examples of how to use the function:

```vb
Sub test()
    MsgBox ExplicitSum("=5+sum(A1:D1)/20")
    'Displays "=5+(A1+B1+C1+D1)/20"
End Sub

Sub ExampleUsage()
    'Put the formula back into the cell after transforming
    Range("E1").Formula = ExplicitSum(Range("E1").Formula)
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Run on every cell with SUM in its formula
    If LCase(Target.Cells(1,1).Formula) Like "*sum(*" Then Target.Cells(1,1).Formula = ExplicitSum(Target.Cells(1,1).Formula)
End Sub
```

1. Will work with complex formulas.
2. Will work with multiple SUMS in the same formula.
3. Will work with Named Ranges inside the Sum.

Comment: I am waiting until someone posts an expression tree parser and uses that.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with .Precedents:

```
Sub expandSUM()
    Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(I1:I5)" 'the formula must be in the cell
    Output = "=SUM("
    
    For Each cl In Range("A1").Precedents
        Output = Output & "+" & cl.Address(False, False)
    Next
    Debug.Print Replace(Output, "(+", "(") & ")"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to do this via string manipulations.

I tested with

- Before `=SUM(C2:C4,E2:G2,D7:E8)`
- After `=$C$2+$C$3+$C$4+$E$2+$F$2+$G$2+$D$7+$E$7+$D$8+$E$8`

Usage, call `ExpandSum()` with the target cell as an argument

```
Public Sub ExpandSum(ByVal r_target As Range)

    Dim f As String
    f = Mid(r_target.Formula, 2)
    ' Is it a SUM function
    If Left(f, 3) = "SUM" Then
        ' Take the arguments of SUM
        f = Mid(f, 5, Len(f) - 5)
        
        ' make an array of string with each
        ' arument
        Dim parts() As String
        parts = Split(f, ",")
        
        Dim i As Long, n As Long
        n = UBound(parts) + 1
        Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
        Dim col As New Collection
        For i = 1 To n
            ' for each argument find the range of cells
            Set rng = Range(parts(i - 1))
            For Each cl In rng
                ' Add each cell in range into a list
                col.Add cl.Address
            Next
        Next i
        ' Transfer list to array
        ReDim parts(0 To col.Count - 1)
        For i = 1 To col.Count
            parts(i - 1) = col(i)
        Next i
        ' Combine parts into one expression
        ' ["A1","A2","A3"] => "A1+A2+A3"
        f = Join(parts, "+")
        r_target.Formula = "=" & f
    End If

End Sub
```

Example of calling with the current selection

```
Public Sub ThisExpandSum()
    Call ExpandSum(Selection)
End Sub
```

**Caveats** I don't know how it will behave if the sum contains literal values, or cells from different sheets. That can be functionality to be added later.

Comment: Your function doesn't work if there are any terms before the Sum in the formula. Any input like `=1 + Sum(A1:B1)` doesn't work.

Comment: @Toddleson - true but that wasn't a requirement in the _op_ question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the next function, please:

```
Function SUMbyItems(strFormula As String) As String
   If strFormula = "" Then Exit Function
  Dim rng As Range, Ar As Range, c As Range, strF As String
  Set rng = Range(left(Split(strFormula, "(")(1), Len(Split(strFormula, "(")(1)) - 1))
  For Each Ar In rng.Areas
        For Each c In Ar.cells
            strF = strF & c.Address(0, 0) & "+"
        Next c
  Next
  strF = left(strF, Len(strF) - 1)
  SUMbyItems = "=SUM(" & strF & ")"
End Function
```

It can be used, selecting a cell having a SUM formula containing a range and run the next Sub:

```
Sub testSumByItems()
   Debug.Print SUMbyItems(ActiveCell.Formula)
End Sub
```

If it returns what you want and you need changing the range formula with its expanded version, you can use (in the above testing Sub):

```
  ActiveCell.Formula = SUMbyItems(ActiveCell.Formula)
```

Comment: Your function doesn't check if the formula actually has a SUM. And splits on the first bracket found. Any input like `=Count(A1:B5) / Sum(A1:B5)` would not be transformed properly.

Comment: @Toddleson: Of course, not! this is not my function. It is the answer at the OP question. Did he ask about such a formula and I missed it? Would you like it to also put some money in your account, too...?

Comment: Yes please! I would like that very much.

Comment: @Toddleson: Then, please wait a little... :) Check your account in about an hour.